# Status bar not hiding automatically in Android app

Tags: android

I have created an application for testing out the hiding of the status bar in an Android app. From [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status), I have learnt that setting `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility()` with the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` hides the status bar. So, I wrote this code:

```java
package com.example.windowmanage;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int VISIBILITY= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(VISIBILITY);
        }
    }
}
```

After launching the app, the status bar gets hidden, but when I pull down the status bar from the top, it stays there unless something else happens. Here is a GIF which demonstrates the behaviour:
[image]

Why is this happening and how to fix this error? For your information, I am using a Samsung Galaxy M21 for running the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` fixed the issue.